# Datepicker Not Working on Laravel 5, Jquery 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, laravel-5, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to build a very simple form the allows a user to submit a date. I want to use a datepicker to input the date, but it will not work. The input just shows up as a text box and I get jquery errors, no calendar is displayed at all. If it relates, I'm using Laravel 5.4 for the application with bootstrap css/js.

Also, I checked and datepicker is not mentioned at all in the bootstrap JS

### Attached Styles/Scripts

```
<!-- Styles -->
{!! Html::style('css/bootstrap.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('css/app.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('css/jquery-ui.min.css') !!}
<!-- Scripts -->
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery-3.2.0.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}

<script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        } );
    </script>
```

### Form View

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

### Here are the CONSOLE ERRORS

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://.../employees/create:37:23)
at mightThrow (http://.../js/jquery-3.2.0.js:3583:29)
at process (http://.../js/jquery-3.2.0.js:3651:12) undefined
 jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.0.js:3860
 process @ jquery-3.2.0.js:3655

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (create:37)
at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.0.js:3583)
at process (jquery-3.2.0.js:3651)
```

Comment: Are you sure datepicker is included in your version of jQueryUI? You can download custom versions here http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: Did you tried jQuery version 2.* ?

Comment: I have tried it on version 2.* and still getting the same error. I've also tried a customer version that @SergeiKutanov  suggested

Comment: Resolved! See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have resolved the issue by finding a javascript file being loaded at the end of my header file. It was totally unnoticed, but it caused a conflict to prevent it from working.